# Why is an IFRAME inside a CDATA section breaking the parser?

Tags: html, xml, iframe, xhtml, cdata

I have a CDATA section that contains an embedded iframe declaration like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div>before iframe</div>
    <iframe id="xml_test">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xml_data>
            <node>
                <![CDATA[
                    "<iframe src=\"http://imgur.com\"></iframe>"
                ]]>
            </node>
        </xml_data>
    </iframe>
    <div>after iframe</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the resulting DOM in several browsers it seems the `iframe` declaration inside the CDATA section is not ignored:

[image]

The HTML is also messed-up:

[image]

Removing the closing `iframe` tag from the CDATA section fixes it:

[image]

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<iframe>` elements cannot have their contents defined inline like that. The contents of the tag are all being ignored up until the first `</iframe>`, which closes the element with `id=xml_test`; the rest of the parsing should make sense in that light.

Comment: Isn't it similar to doing this? - `<iframe src="URL" more attributes>alternative content for browsers which do not support iframe</iframe>`

Comment: Also, there are no longer any browsers of significance that "do not support iframe". `<iframe>` tags should be left empty.